# Prettier's format on save messes up .jsx files

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I have `format on save` enabled, and it works fine in .js files but when I try to save code in my .jsx files everything gets messed up. How can I configure my prettier to avoid this problem without disabling `format on save`?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using VS Code, try adding this to your settings.json file:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "[javascriptreact]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

for anyone who encounter this, you probably have some other VS Code plugin installed, such as `Beautify` which is recommended by vscode. Uninstall it and prettier should works now.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. Having multiple code formatters will indeed mess up the code.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Disable the Prettier VSCode extension if you already have Prettier managed by ESLint.

I had a similar issue with .mdx files (which I use for Storybook). I have formatOnSave enabled and use Prettier through ESLint for a Vue project.
Prettier would break the .mdx files by removing meaningful empty lines, resulting in a nice error: "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag."

The solution for me was to disable the Prettier extension in VSCode. You don't need it anyway, because you already have a Prettier managed by ESLint, and *that* one does not break the .mdx files.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same situation. I uninstalled extensions like prettier, etc. and it is working fine.

Comment: I like this option but wouldn’t it be cool to have prettier to auto format code properly ..