# JSX Render function not recognized by Visual Studio

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio, jsx

I'm following along with a great AWS tutorial, but I believe Visual Studio is failing to recognize my JSX return function as HTML. Has anybody else had this problem?

VS wants it to look as follows:

```
render() {
    return ( <
        section className = "section auth" >
        <
        div className = "container" >
        <
        h1 > Register < /h1> <FormErrors formerrors = { this.state.errors }/ >

        <
        form onSubmit = { this.handleSubmit } >
        <
        div className = "field" >
        <
        p className = "control" >
        <
        input className = "input"
        type = "text"
        id = "username"
        aria - describedby = "userNameHelp"
        placeholder = "Enter username"
        value = { this.state.username }
        onChange = { this.onInputChange }
        /> < /
```

[visual studio auto-formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0za.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Prettier's format on save messes up .jsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279071/prettiers-format-on-save-messes-up-jsx-files)

This was the answer.  Disable all formatters other than Prettier!!