# How do I configure Prettier format usable React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier

So I started learning React from this (https://youtu.be/Dorf8i6lCuk?t=1946) tutorial and got stuck trying to save a file. The video recommends getting prettier and I did and then when I save the file it auto-formats code into something that doesn't work.
eg:
[image: Example of a badly formatted save file]

as per the suggestion a jsx file:
[image]

as per suggestion 2: already in Javascript React:
[image]

As per the suggestion in the solutions:

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing the extension to `.jsx` and see if the error indication persists?

Comment: Yep looks like it persists

Comment: Go to the bottom right, click on JavaScript, and select JavaScript React when the menu pops up. Alternatively, using `.tsx` will automatically set the language to TypeScript React, so if you know TypeScript, it's an easier option

Comment: try fixing the syntax then running prettier as otherwise it fails

Comment: @LoganDevine I'm assuming the formatting was correct, but prettier messed it up when it was in JS mode

Comment: Also make sure you've set prettier to the default formatter, not whatever you were using before or whatever the VSCode default is

Comment: Change extension to JSX, and undo the broken formatting, then save again.

Comment: Hello its already in Javasrcipt React and its chaining the formating on save @LoganDevine

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) There's no real value to the images here.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to settings > Extensions > uncheck - Enable/disable checkbox. **Or Remove all together.**

Change code to: (Notice the differences in my code to yours, your `div` tags are open and `return` does not have the `divs` wrapped in `()`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello!
    </div> //this was giving you the error before 
  )
}

export default App
```

I'd also double check your version of react that you are running.
If the version is different from the Tutorials, this could cause issues.

This might help:
[Prettier's format on save messes up .jsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279071/prettiers-format-on-save-messes-up-jsx-files)

Comment: Did that and well.. (check the main thread for how the formatted changed the code)

Comment: What is your React version compared to the tutorials? Did you remove the Prettier?

Comment: Currently on React 17.0.2 and uninstalling prettier does not fix it.

Comment: using yarn or npm? try npm install, or yarn install depending on what you're using, might be a dependency issue. I just created the app following the same process in the video and not seeing any issue on my end, but I never added prettier. check versions of npm and yarn as well

Comment: Fixed it! So it turns out I don't need a .jsx file but the format at the bottom needs to be set to javascript react. (for a .js file) that's the part I messed up!

Answer (score 1):

Following @AlexB801 's advice I have fixed the thing. It turns out you must NOT change the extension to .jsx but only change the formatter. Attaching an image. Also another thing to be noted here is that this was not an issue with Prettier. like so:
[image]